# How to open Instagram app via Mobile and Instagram Web via windows

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, web, instagram

I have a responsive website.
on mobile i want my instagram anchor tag to open the app 
and on windows i want it to open the webpage 
i can do each separately but not simultaneously.
this works for mobile:
instagram://user?username=MYUSERNAME  
i guess this is called deep linking

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out
since my website is on bootstrap and it is responsive I made 2 sets of links.
one will appear for desktop size and the other for mobile and tablet.
now on desktop it will open web pages and on mobile and tablet it will open the app.